# Font similar to base of OldConstructedCaps without the drafter's construction lines

Tags: font-identification, font-recommendation

I'm trying to find a way to more easily mask the actual letter area of the OldConstructedCaps font so that I can change the color of the construction lines after rasterizing the text (eg black letter with light gray construction lines.

A font similar to the letter portion only of that would be the easiest that I can think of but cannot find one. It's similar to times new Román, but "rounder" over all and a bit thicker (but not as thick as the bold varíen). Has serif that I would like to keep sharp.

Alternatively, a suggestion on a way to mask it sufficiently without spending hours selecting individual pixels. I've tried various uses of expand, contract and smooth on the selection of the character but am unsatisfied with the results I am achieving.

[image: Screen]

Just incase my upload here didn't work, here's an example of the font I'm trying to modify: B https://imgur.com/gallery/V1PIOD2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typography used in those structural schemes is usually a Classical Ancient Roman. I think in your case it's a **Garamond**

[image: Garamond bold]

Using a font with those estructure lines could help you with a part of the job:

[Initial Caps](https://fontzone.net/font-details/initial-caps-3-normal) via fontzone.net

[image: Initial]